Struggling with ImportError: attempted relative import above top-level package
I have a config_loader class, this is consumed by my tool1 class and tool2 class (and others). I am trying to run my scripts on a server using powershell, but my tool.py class (which consumes the config_loader class) is hitting an import error that I can't seem to fix.
For reference, using poetry the tool1.py consumes as e.g.
from config.config_loader.config_loader import Config

class Tool1(Config):
<code> 

When not using poetry and trying to run e.g.
python tool1.py I get the import error.
From tool1.py I have tried ...config.config_loader.config_loader and ....all_tools.config.config_loader.config_loader
But I get ImportError:attempted relative import above top-level package
Am I missing something?
*Note, I usually run this from a pypoetry repo, but I am having to temporarily run this from a windows server. I have directly copy/pasted the repo to the Windows server, but cannot get pypoetry installed on the server. Hence I am having to make mods to get these scripts working.
Tree:
all_tools
|--config
|--|--config_loader
|--|--|--config_loader.py
|--|--|--__init__.py
|--|--__init__.py
|--tool1
|--|-tool1
|--|--|--tool1.py
|--|--|--__init__.py
|--|--script1.py
|--|--script2.py
|--|--__init__.py
|--tool2
|--|-tool2
|--|--|--tool2.py
|--|--|--__init__.py
|--|--script3.py
|--|--__init__.py
|--__init__.py


Life is simplest if you always run python -m whatever.whatever rather than passing filenames. This applies both to your own code (all_tools.tool2.tool2.tool2? Your directory looks strangely laid out) and tools in the ecosystem (pip, pydoc, etc.)

I believe its set out correctly as per pypoetry. Do you have an answer to the question though?

I mean, the problem is usually running the file by filename (regardless of what your current directory is); to make it work you need to import it from the top-level directory (which will set sys.path correctly as well)

I'm not very experienced when it comes to paths and such, I thought all_tools.config.config_loader.config_loader is importing from the top level directory?

It's intended to, but if you pass the filename instead of -m, or if you are in the wrong directory, the notion of "top level" is set differently. Try adding print("sys.path:", __import__("sys").path) to the top of the tool you're invoking to debug that's actually going on.
